# Call to a member function where() on null Route Model Binding Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, model, binding, routes, null

before so sorry for my bad english. Whats mean that error? "Call to a member function where() on null". In my code need obtain all application for a each category.

Im interesting in use a Model route binding, its works well when I insert a one model, for example: Application. Example:

`Route::get(applications/{application},'ApplicationController@show')->name('apps'));`

But when I try use 2 model in a route, have this problem. Here my code:

`Route::get('categories/{category}/applications/{application:category_id}','ApplicationController@show')->name('apps');`

My models:

```
class Application extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'category_id', 'vote', 'image_src'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'applications_users_states', 'application_id', 'user_id')
            ->withPivot('state_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Log::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

}

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

    public function applications()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Application::class);
    }


}
```

My Controller:

```
  public function show(Category $category,Application $application)
   
    {   
        return $application;

    }
```

Thanks for your time and for your knowledge!!!!!

Comment: welcome to SO ... can u add `ApplicationController@show` code .?

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: side note, your `Category` model's `applications` method is missing the `return`

Comment: oh my god.. its only a return error! Im very ashamed for that! Reallyy thanks youu!!!!!!